# Problemas con el footer de mi web de dibujo

Tags: css, html5

Buen día a todos, de ante mano gracias por su atención.

Necesito ayuda con el `footer` de mi web ya que está en una posición que visualmente se vea mal y apretada (está debajo de mi lienzo o `canvas` pero está demasiado junto).

He intentado cambiarle de posición de varias formas (he usado `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` y nada).

En sí, lo que quiero es bajar un poco mas mi `footer`. Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería muchísimo

Aquí una parte de mi código (lo esencial ya que es demasiado extenso)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #4314af;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 1050px;
}

section {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.tools-board {
  width: 210px;
  padding: 15px 22px 0;
}

.tools-board .row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row .options {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

.tools-board .row.colors {
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tools-board .row:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.row .options .option {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.option #size-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.colors .options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.colors .option {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.drawing-board {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drawing-board canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

footer p {
  font-family: 'REM', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <label class="title">Opciones</label>
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="option active tool" id="brush">
        <img src="img-icon/brush.svg" alt="">
        <span>Pincel</span>
      </li>
      <li class="option tool" id="eraser">
        <img src="img-icon/eraser.svg" alt="">
        <span>Borrador</span>
      </li>
      <li class="option">
        <input type="range" id="size-slider" min="1" max="30" value="5">
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="row colors">

    <label class="title">Colores</label>
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="option"></li>
      <li class="option selected"></li>
      <li class="option"></li>
      <li class="option"></li>
      <li class="option">
        <input type="color" id="color-picker" value="#4A98F7">
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="row buttons">
    <button class="clear-canvas">Limpiar Lienzo</button>
    <button class="save-img" id="save-jpg">Guardar en JPG:</button>
    <button class="save-img2" id="save-png">Guardar en PNG:</button>
  </div>

  </section>

  <section class="drawing-board">

    <canvas></canvas>

  </section>

</div>

<footer>
  <p>© 2023 Hecho por: </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Pero cual es el resultado que esperas? Porque he recreado tu sitio y no le encuentro mucha cosa, puedes poner un esquema o dibujo de lo que quieres? Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para ello.